# nslookup shows wrong data

Tags: active-directory

I am currently an administrator and have about 150 windows systems running.
The previous administrator turned out be be a real nightmare for me before he
left.

The network assignes some windows servers (static IPs) while the rest of the
machines are assigned IP address through a DHCP server. When I look at the
DHCP snapin in the active directory, I can see system name and mac addresses
assigned with ip addresses.

If i do a nslookup for the same system it shows a different IP address and
name. What I mean is, computer A on my DHCP list is assigned 10.10.10.100. if
I do a nslookup through command prompt for 10.10.10.100 it shows a completely
different computer name Z and not A. and the funny thing is if I do a nslookup
for computer name Z the ip address turns out to be completely different as
well ( not 10.10.10.100)

Is there a reason why it would behave this way?

Most of the PCs run a win-server 2003 standard (SP2)

Comment: Thanks for your question. This is off-topic for this stack (I've already voted to move it to Server-Fault where it should be on-topic).

Comment: A long time ago, I have had a similar problem with nslookup: https://superuser.com/questions/735468/strange-nslookup-response . Never got a response :)

Comment: Are the client's DNS servers AD integrated? Does running the lookup against other DCs/DNS produce the same incorrect results?  `nslookup hostA dc1`, `nslookup hostA dns2`, etc. Is DHCP dynamic DNS registration running? Is it working?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you're getting while using nslookup to resolve the ip address is coming from your Reverse Lookup zone in DNS, and the record being returned is stale. You should enable scavenging on the DNS server and on your Forward and Reverse Lookup zones so that stale records get removed.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd check is the `hosts` file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\`. Maybe there are some entries overwritten there.

Then I'd check your DNS server configuration as you can have different reverse lookup entries than forward lookup entries. E.g. if you do a `nslookup 10.10.10.100`, the system is actually searching for a PTR record for `100.10.10.10.in-addr.arpa` (notice the IP is backwards in this notation). This one can point to a completely different machine than `computerA`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

You can do this by entering following command:

> ipconfig /flushdns

This is my first tought about this matter. I assume your previous administrator changed some ip's and still remembers them in cache of client/server.

Does this help you ?

Edit:Note that support for windows server 2003 is at end of service on july 14, 2015 !

Comment: Yes i have tried ipconfig/flushdns on the server, but of no use.

Comment: So all the servers are configured as DHCP? Maybe its because they all give ip adresses in the same range this anomaly occurs. Maybe try to set some ranges? I'm absolutly not sure if this would resolve this issue.

I think restarting the whole thing isn't an option ?

Edit: you have one DHCP ?

Comment: `ipconfig/flushdns` will clear the DNS client cache on the server, not the DNS server cache. The answer you're getting while running nslookup is from the DNS server, not the DNS client cache.